# Filtering and returning element in array according to some given preference

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose if I have two arrays - one as the preference in order and another the data set and I want to return first element from data set matching first matching preference.

For example

```
const userPref = ['banana', 'apple', 'peach'];

const givenFruits = [
  { name: 'apple', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'orange', color: 'orange' },
  { name: 'pear', color: 'yellow' },
  { name: 'cherry', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'grape', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'peach', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'coconut', color: 'brown' }
];

function findFavFruit() {
  userPref.forEach((pref) => {
    givenFruits.forEach((fruit) => {
        if(pref === fruit.name) {
            return fruit;
        }
    });
 });
}

console.log('findFavFruit(): ' + JSON.stringify(findFavFruit(), null, 2));
```

This is always returning `undefined`. It supposed to return `apple` ONLY as it is user first matching preference and is found first in givenFruits.

What I am doing wrong in above code? And is there a cleaner way (avoid double `forEach`) in Javascript?

Comment: Your `findFavFruit` doesn't return anything. Remember `forEach` is a higher-order function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the givenFruits using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to test if the current fruit is inside the array of favorite fruits..

Example:

```js
function findFavoriteFruit(preferences, arrayOfFruits) {
  for (let fruit of arrayOfFruits) {
    if (preferences.includes(fruit.name)) {
      return fruit;
    }
  }
}

const userPref = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach'];

const givenFruits = [
  { name: 'apple', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'orange', color: 'orange' },
  { name: 'banana', color: 'yellow' },
  { name: 'pear', color: 'yellow' },
  { name: 'cherry', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'grape', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'peach', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'coconut', color: 'brown' }
];

const favoriteFruit = findFavoriteFruit(userPref, givenFruits);

console.log(favoriteFruit);
```

This implementation is the fastest (comparing with other answers) as you can see [here](https://jsperf.com/find-the-favorite-fruit-2).

Comment: I need `apple` only

Comment: I think you mean `of` not `in` but this won't work either. It would be `userPref.includes(fruit.name)`

Comment: I was updating :).

Comment: I'm on mobile but I think with find the other answer will be faster.

Comment: It will not be, I already updated the test and the implementation with find is (2% - 5%) slower.

Comment: @MarceloAlves, genuine curiosity. If you place your code in a function, as in the above solution, is this solution still faster? Or take the function step out of the other solution? I would assume .find() would be pretty well optimized.

Comment: I don't know. I'm going to update the answer and the tests do add the loop inside a function, one sec.

Comment: @SimplyComplexable I updated my answer. My implementation still wins by 0.2% hehehe <3 (Irrelevant, but good to know)

Comment: @SimplyComplexable Now my implementation is winning by 1%. Can you check in your mobile?

Comment: @MarceloAlves It crashes on my phone. On my computer yours is consistently faster though. Very interesting, though, would not have expected that result.

Answer (score 1):

Select the first element of `userPref` array to compare `fruit.name` to within `.find()` function, return result.

To return only the property value, for example, `"name"`, you can pass the property as a string to the function and use bracket notation to reference and return the property

```js
const userPref = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach'];

const [preference] = userPref;

const givenFruits = [
  { name: 'apple', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'orange', color: 'orange' },
  { name: 'banana', color: 'yellow' },
  { name: 'pear', color: 'yellow' },
  { name: 'cherry', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'grape', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'peach', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'coconut', color: 'brown' }
];

function findFavFruit(pref, prop, arr) {
   return arr.find(fruit => pref === fruit[prop])[prop];
}

let res = findFavFruit(preference, "name", givenFruits);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Use find instead of filter as only the first object is needed.

Comment: sorry if I didn't explain clearly.See the updated question that should still return `apple`

Comment: @αƞjiβ `"banana"` is not removed at edited Question, `"banana"` is at index `1` of `userPref` array. How is `"apple"` selected as the value to match in `givenFruits`?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should provide some checks whether given keys exist, but here is the basic:

`(givenFruits.find((v)=>{return v.name == userPref[0]})).name`

Don't know why to iterate over `userPref` if you only need first key.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above solutions are correct, I just wanted to clarify what the issue with your code was. See below:

```
function findFavFruit() {
  let userFruit;
  userPref.forEach((pref) => {
    givenFruits.forEach((fruit) => {
        if(pref === fruit.name) {
            userFruit = fruit;
        }
    });
 });
 return userFruit;
}
```

This would return the fruit if it was found or undefined if it wasn't.